# postgres - select IDs of duplicates EXCLUDE the original ones

Tags: database, postgresql

Have:

```
1 John  NYC
2 John  NYC
3 John  NYC
4 Lucy  LA
5 Lucy  LA
6 Bob   LA
```

I'd like to find ids of duplicates(based on multiple columns) but not include originals, originals would be with lowest keys.

So I'd return 2,3,5 because they have same name and location.

There are numerous ways to find dups based on count and do inner join to return all ids on StackOveflow but not like this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Select a.id from table a
inner join table b on a.id > b.id and
a.name=b.name and a.loc=b.loc
```

Comment: WOW, amazing! exactly what I needed. Thanks.